# Overflow with elements out of the flow

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that I have have positioned on the left and right sides of the screen (using float and/or absolute positioning, I have found many ways to position them). In the middle I have a single div that keeps the content of my website centered. My problem is that when I have my browser at a small width those outside divs are forced in and mess everything up in the center. When I have my browser at a small width I want a scroll bar to appear so that a user and scroll left or right to see the divs outside the center content. I am using overflow:scroll on the body element but that doesn't do anything. I also need to use

Here is the basic structure

```
<body>
  <div id="navLeft">
  <div id="navRight">
  <centered content/all of webpage>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS for the body and side divs

```
body { 
background: #A2F0FA url('images/bg_site.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x; 
font: 13px Arial, Sans-Serif; 
color: #525252;
overflow:scroll;
```

}

```
#navLeft {
border: 5px solid #fff;
width:220px;
height: 260px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:28%;
opacity:0.85;
```

}

```
#navRight {
border: 5px solid #fff;
width:220px;
height: 260px;
float:right;
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:85%;
opacity:0.85;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can try some negative margin on body's side.

**but** you won'nt be able to show the left aside on small screen  so if content is important, you loose it :

`body {margin:0 -220px ; /* width of aside element */`.

[Test the idea here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzAHf/)

Best is to check via javaScript on load and resize width of window &  body  & if an horizontal scroll is there and its scrollright value.

Then reset the scrollright to a proper value without annoying your visitor.